# How to SELECT TOP 3 Values in to 3 Columns with specific rule?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, pivot, greatest-n-per-group

So I would like to find out the top 3 sellers(by Amount) in each sales month for each customer.

Original Table:

[image: Original Table]

```
create table q2(Sales_Date date, Customer_ID varchar(256), Item varchar(256), Amount float);        
                
INSERT INTO q2              
VALUES              
    ('2018/8/1' ,'AAA'  , 'Apple'   , 5600),
     ('2018/8/8'    ,'AAA'  , 'Nike'    , 500),
     ('2018/8/9'    ,'AAA'  , 'Pear'    , 600),
     ('2018/8/10'   ,'AAA'  , 'Kindle', 900),
     ('2018/8/1'    ,'BBB'  , 'Cola', 20),
     ('2018/9/12'   ,'BBB'  , 'LEGO' , 240),
     ('2018/9/13'   ,'CCC'  , 'Apple' , 2500),
     ('2018/9/14'   ,'CCC'  , 'Kindle' , 5000),
     ('2018/7/4'    ,'CCC'  , 'Nike' , 1000),
     ('2018/9/7'    ,'CCC'  , 'Pear' , 300),
     ('2018/9/7'    ,'CCC'  , 'LEGO' , 50);
```

Expect Output

[image: Expect Output]

I have try different methods but none of them work. How can I achieve this?

So far, I can only retrieve the Top seller with the code, but this is not enough.

```
SELECT
    m.Sales_month,
    m.Customer_ID,
    m.Item
FROM(
      SELECT
        Month(Sales_Date) as Sales_month,  
        Customer_ID, 
        Amount,
        Item,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Month(Sales_Date), Customer_ID ORDER BY Amount Desc) AS 'rank'
        FROM q2  
    ) as m
WHERE m.rank = 1;
```

Many Thanks!!

Comment: The now deleted @GMB answer looks correct to me, use: `WHERE m.rank <= 3` in the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the top 3 sales per customer and per month, in columns.

Ranking records per customer and per month is a good start. We can then filter on the top three records per group, and pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select sales_month, customer_id, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then item end) as item_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then item end) as item_2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then item end) as item_3
from (
    select q.*,
        date_format(sales_date, '%Y-%m-01') as sales_month,  
        row_number() over (partition by customer_id, date_format(sales_date, '%Y-%m-01') order by amount desc) as rn
    from q2  
) q
where rn <= 3
group by sales_month, customer_id
```

Note that this includes the sales year in the grouping, as opposed to your original code, that only used the month. This is handy if your data spreads over more than one year.

Comment: Thank a lot, it's exactly what I need. But why use max() as an aggregate function in the first select statement? If I change different aggregate function such MIN(), will the result be different?